# Is it possible to change Ruby's frozen object handling behaviour?

Tags: ruby

I am submitting solutions to Ruby puzzles on codewars.com and experimenting with how locked into the testing enviroment I am for one of the challenges.

I can redefine the classes used to test my solution but they are defined by the system after I submit my code. If I freeze these objects, the system cannot write over them but a RunTime error is raised when it tries to.

I'm fairly new to Ruby, so I'm not sure which parts (other than falsiness and truthiness) are impossible to override. Can I use Ruby code to force modification of frozen objects to silently fail instead of terminate the program or is that bound up in untouchable things like the assignment operator or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is that if you might want to modify an object later, you shouldn't freeze it. That's inherent in the whole concept of "freezing" an object. But since you asked, note that you can test whether an object is frozen with:

```
 obj.frozen?
```

So if those pesky `RuntimeError`s are getting you down, one solution is to use a guard clause like:

```
 obj.do_something! if !obj.frozen?
```

If you want to make the guard clauses implicit, you can redefine the "problem" methods using a monkey patch:

```
 class Array
   # there are a couple other ways to do this
   # read up on Ruby metaprogramming if you want to know
   alias :__pop__ :pop
   def pop
     frozen? ? nil : __pop__
   end
 end
```

If you want your code to work seamlessly with any and all Ruby libraries/gems, adding behavior to built-in methods like this is probably a bad idea. In this case, I doubt it will cause any problems, but whenever you choose to start hacking on Ruby's core classes, you have to be ready for the possible consequences.